# Using inherited classes in .NET web API POST/PUT method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I can't figure out how I can work with inherited classes in an web API controller. I **have to** create **only one** API controller to create and update inherited objects in the database.

Similar to my models (to all these models exists a Dto):

```
public class Animal
{
    public virtual string Name {get; set;} // e.g. Harry
    public virtual string Type {get; set;} // e.g. Dog
}

public class AnimalDto
{
    public string Name;
    public Type Type;
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public virtual bool CanBark {get; set;} // e.g. true
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public virtual bool CanMiau {get; set;}
}
```

I already tried to use the json in the controller. But there was the json always `null`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post([FromBody]JObject json)
{
    // idk what's going here?!
}
```

My controller now, but that cuts off all attributes of Dog or Cat model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post([FromBody]AnimalDto animal)
{
    // idk what's going here?!
}
```

I'm using .NET Core 2.0

Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT**

What if I want to do this dynamically? Something like:

```
var animal = json.ToObject<Animal>();
var actualAnimal = json.ToObject<typeof(animal.Type)>();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please show the AnimalDto code as well.

Comment: @Dimitar Have added it

Comment: Just because you, presumably, have a convention that the `Type` property of the `Animal` must be one of `Dog` or `Cat` and furthermore that this is correlated with the actual subtype being used (which is what I presume you're doing), how do you think a generic JSON parser is going to know about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I already tried to use the json in the controller. But there was the json always null

The reason why you always get `null` is that you didn't declare the correct `Type`. You're not supposed to receive a `string` type of animal via `[FromBody]`.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post([FromBody]string json)
    public ActionResult Post([FromBody]Dog dog)
    {
        // now you get the dog
    }
```

As a side note, if you don't care the type at all, one approach is to declare a `dynamic` type:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] dynamic json)
{
    return new JsonResult(json); 
}
```

In this scenario, the dynamic type is `JObject`, you could cast them to any type as you like:

```
public IActionResult Post(/*[ModelBinder(typeof(AnimalModelBinder))]*/[FromBody] JObject json)
{
    var animal=json.ToObject<Animal>();
    var dog = json.ToObject<Dog>();
    return new JsonResult(json); 
}
```

> My controller now, but that cuts off all attributes of Dog or Cat model

If you would like to use the `AnimalDto`, you should make the properties accessible:

```
    public class AnimalDto
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public string Type;
        public string Type{get;set;}
    }
```

**[Edit]**

> What if I want to do this dynamically? Something like:
>
> ```
> var animal = json.ToObject<Animal>();
> var actualAnimal = json.ToObject<typeof(animal.Type)>();
> ```

If we want to cast the json to some particular type, we must firstly know what the target `Type` is . But your `animal.Type` property is a type of `String`, and that might be a by-convention string. If this `Type` property is exactly the class name without namespace , e.g.

- `Cat.Type` must equals `Cat`
- `Dog.Type` must equals `Dog`
- `Fish.Type` must equals `Fish`

then you can you use `Type.GetType()` to resolve the target type. For example :

```cs
// typename : the Animal.Type property
// ns : the namespace string 
private Type ResolveAnimalType(string typename,string ns){
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ns)){ ns = "App.Models";}
    typename= $"{ns}.{typename}";
    var type=Type.GetType(
        typename,
        assemblyResolver:null,  // if you would like load from other assembly, custom this resovler
        typeResolver: (a,t,ignore)=> a == null ? 
            Type.GetType(t, false, ignore) : 
            a.GetType(t, false, ignore),
        throwOnError:true,
        ignoreCase:false
    );
    return type;
}
```

Anyway, **you could custom the way we resolve the target `Type` according to your own needs**. And then **cast the json object to your wanted `Type` by method `ToObject<T>()`**:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] JObject json)
{
    var typename = json.Value<string>("type");
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(typename)) 
        ModelState.AddModelError("json","any animal must provide a `type` property");
    
    // resolve the target type
    var t= ResolveAnimalType(typename,null);

    // get the method of `.ToObject<T>()`
    MethodInfo mi= typeof(JObject)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(m=> m.Name=="ToObject" && m.GetParameters().Length==0 && m.IsGenericMethod  )
        .FirstOrDefault()
        ?.MakeGenericMethod(t); // ToObject<UnknownAnimialType>()

    var animal = mi?.Invoke(json,null);
    return new JsonResult(animal); 
}
```

Comment: That worked! But what if I want to do this more dynamically? -> Please see my edit

Comment: @R.Müller I've updated my answer  and created a demo to make sure it works. If you have any questions, please feel free to update me.

Comment: Man, YOU ARE MY HERO! Thank you so so so so much! You litrally saved my life! :D Helped A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned that your are using either .NET Core or .NET Framework, but the main reason of this kind of behavior is model binding module which maps data from HTTP requests to action method parameters. I think you'd better to develop your own custom model binder and use it instead of the default one.

[Here you can read more about custom model binding in asp .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

[Here you can read more about custom model binding in asp .NET MVC](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1261/custom-model-binder-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: How can I do this? Can you give me an example for he code above? (.net core 2.0 btw)

Comment: For sure, You can find some polymorphic model binder here:
https://www.tutorialdocs.com/article/webapi-data-binding.html