# Multiple .NET User types login in one API route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, routes

I have 2 types of user:

```cs
public abstract class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Customer : User
{
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Vendor : User
{
    public List<int> PriceList { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to have an api path like : `/api/user/login` :

```cs
[HttpPost("login")]
public ActionResult</* MyUser */> Login(...)
{
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to create only one method returning my different types ?

If no, what would be the best architecture ?

- Two routes: `/api/customer/login` and `/api/vendor/login`
- Two routes: `/api/user/customer/login` and `/api/user/vendor/login`
- One route: `/api/user/login` with an enum in the request telling which user to use

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I think the accepted answer on this post will give you good direction: [using-inherited-classes-in-net-web-api-post-put-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158740/using-inherited-classes-in-net-web-api-post-put-method)

Answer (score 0):

You should create only one method which returns `User`, that will work because both `Vendor` and `Customer` are subclasses of `User`

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public ActionResult<User> Login(...)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But will I have access the fields specific to the subclasses ?

Comment: Yes, you just need to cast your object to a proper subclass, read more about it in this article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions